# how to knockout rows from a sheet

Tags: database, excel, extract

I have thousands of records in sheet B that I want to find in sheet A and delete the entire row in sheet A. They have a common column.  There are no duplicates now, however if there were all would need to be deleted. This is obviously a "take the first key value from sheet B lookup in sheet A and delete, loop sheet A.  Hideously slow but there is no structure to the keys(they are sorted lexically) so no binary search, just pure lexical. How could/would one do that?

Comment: Have you tried adding a vlookup column from A to B, and where there isn't an error, try cell.entirerow.delete?

Comment: Do you need to repeat the whole process again and again? Or its just one time? you can try using `MATCH` in sheet A and then filter the sheet.

Comment: @Harlekuin how would I control the looping, detect a match, then execute cell.entirerow.delete

Comment: @nightcrawler23.  Just execute it once.  I can of course filter inplace and just get the test vector.  What I want is the negative of that, i.e. those rows eliminated.

Comment: @cp. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a vlookup column from A to B, and where there isn't an error, try cell.entirerow.delete. (=iferror(vlookup(),"Fine"))

You can do this with a do loop (replace < values >):

```
x = <first row>

do until sheets("SheetName").cells(x, <column number>) = ""

if sheets("<SheetName>").cells(x, <vlookup col>) != "Fine" then 'For example based on above
    x = x + 1
else
    sheets("SheetName").cells(x, 1).entirerow.delete
end if

loop
```

Comment: Is this to be put in a VBA function.  I need a little more on how to make this actionable if you may.

Comment: @cp. Yes in a VBA sub. Another option would be to add that vlookup and filter based on the new column and delete (i.e. where it doesn't say fine)

Comment: Thanks, I will pick the latter this is a "use once" project